# Filebeat "name:" from file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have a file for example /tmp/filebeatname. 
In this file i have id - for example 324sjdf-13212-123123-1312.
I want put this ID in filebeat config (filebeat.yml) in to be 
"name: 324sjdf-13212-123123-1312"
I try with

```
"name:  /tmp/filebeatname"
"name:  $(cat /tmp/filebeatname)"
```

Comment: Sorry not very clear on what you are trying to achieve. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure filebeat is already shipping the filename somewhere in what's sent to logstash (and it's been asked around here too).

Comment: I want to give a name to my shipper (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-general-options.html#configuration-general )
In docs example the shipper is named "my-shipper"
I want to take the name from file where the file contain some name. 
With another words I have file "/tmp/somefile" in this file:
     "cat /tmp/somefile"
Output:
      "my-shipper"
I want to take the value("my-shipper") from the file(/tmp/somefile) and use it in filebeat.yml as value: 
       "name: my-shipper"
I don't want to use "sed", "awk" and so on.